# Snowflake - Invalid Identifier

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi i am getting invalid identifier for “owner”while executing this query below,i have tried single/double quotes and tilda

in show roles i have comments with email address and i am trying to get owner and owner email address.

comments example - {RoleType:"Access",Workload:"RTR",Application:"Business Automation",AppName:"RTR",Contact:"sabfinw@gmail.com",Director:"sabrish133@gmail.com",Environment:"DEV",Owner:"sanjayd.980@gmail.com",VP:"sabrish"}

```
show roles;

    select owner,split_part(b.data,':',2) as Owner_Email from (
        select a.value::string as data from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())),
        lateral flatten(input=>split("comment",',')) a) b where b.data like '%Owner%';
```

Comment: Ah, you are just treating it like a string, thus the prior JSON comment does not apply. Therefore the problem is in the outer select there is no object called `owner` to select as `data` is the only thing from the inner select accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select the value from the inner select

```
SELECT 
    owner,
    split_part(b.data,':',2) as Owner_Email 
FROM (
    SELECT r.owner,
        a.value::string as data
    FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) r,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split(r.comment, ',')) a
) b 
WHERE b.data LIKE '%Owner%';
```

Or you can use the QUALIFY clause to filter in the same time like:

```
SELECT r.owner,
    split_part(a.value::string, ':', 2) as Owner_Email
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) r,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split(r.comment, ',')) a
QUALIFY a.value::string LIKE '%Owner%'
```

Comment: Hi simeon,invalid identifier  "r.owner " and "r.comment",tried within single quotes still same

Comment: @Virally I have not run this SQL, so am just guess from looking at the doc's, but the quote should not matter at all. Well no quotes means the string is (default) goes to uppercase, where-as double quote means leave it as you type it, which will not match unless you change to uppercase, while single quote is a string literal, aka not a column name at all. but if you just do `SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))` that will give you the names of the columns. Just check that `SELECT owner, comment FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))` works. Then do the split/filter bits

Comment: yes simeon but not able to get the result,any other way without hitting invalid identifiers